# update two remote api and retry multiple time

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

My goal is to fetch data from two remote api and update the data from the two api simultaneously. If the first api update pass and the second api update fails, all update should be reverse. I am having issue in making sure all data is fetch and update at the same time. Please see my current code below. I am working in node.js environment. Thanks.

```
const remote1 =  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
const remote2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'

var data1;
var data2;

fetch(remote1)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data1 = data)

fetch(remote1)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data2 = data)

const trys= 3; 
function updateApi() {
    return new Promise((ok, fail) => { 
        setTimeout(() => data1.id = 2, data2.id = 3 ? ok("OK!") : fail("Error"), 6000);
    });
}

async function Retry(updateApi,  count = trys) {
if (count > 0) {
    const result = await updateApi().catch(e => e);
        if (result === "Error" ) { 
            return await Retry(updateApi,  count - 1) }             
        return result
        }
    return `Tried ${trys} times and failed`;
}

Retry(updateApi).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use promise as like callback, `Promise` is just future value,

```js
const remote1 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
const remote2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'

var data1 = fetch(remote1)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data1 = data)

var data2 = fetch(remote1)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data2 = data)

function updateApi() {
    // waiting for both `data1` and `data2` to resolve...
    return Promise.all([data1, data2]).then(_ => {
        data1.id = 2;
        data2.id = 3;
    })
}

async function Retry(updateApi, count = 3) {
    if (!count) throw `Tried ${count} times and failed`
    try {
        await updateApi();
    } catch (error) {
        await Retry(updateApi, count - 1)
    }
}

Retry(updateApi)
    .then(() => console.log({ data1, data2 }))
    .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solves it and easy for me to understand. Thanks again.